# Passing array of objects to the List component as props and iterate it using map method. But getting error: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```
data.js:-
        
        export default [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'Bertie Yates',
              age: 29,
              image:
                'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: 'Hester Hogan',
              age: 32,
              image:
                'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-3_rxtqvi.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: 'Larry Little',
              age: 36,
              image:
                'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: 'Sean Walsh',
              age: 34,
              image:
                'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              name: 'Lola Gardner',
              age: 29,
              image:
                'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg',
            },
          ];
        
        
        
        App.js
        
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        import data from './data';
        import List from './List'
        
        class App extends Component() {
          constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
              people: data,
            };
           }
           handleclick=()=>{
             this.setstate({
               people:[]
             });
           }
          render(){
             
            return (
            
            <div className="App">
              <h3> birthday today</h3>
              <List peoples={this.state.people}/>
              <button onClick={this.handleclick}>Clear All</button>
            </div>
          );
          };
        }
        
        export default App;
        
        List.js:-
        
        
        import React from 'react';
        
        const List=(peoples)=>{
            // const peoples=props.peoples
            return(
                 <div>
                {peoples.map(person =>{
                return <div key={person.id}>
           
    
             <p>{person.name} {person.age}</p>
                     <img src={person.image}/>
        </div>
                 })}
                </div>
            )
        }
        export default List;
```

I want to pass the data(array of objects) inside data.js to List component as props and iterate it using map method to render array of objects. but it gives error: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined. Also created a button so that when I click on that button Lists gets clear. Your help must be Aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> const List=(peoples)=>{

you should destructure the props to get peoples, like:

```
const List=({ peoples })=>{
```

or

```
const List=(props) => {
 const { peoples } = props;
```

**Edit:**

```
class App extends Component() {
```

should be

```
class App extends Component {
```

Comment: Have tried this also but giving same error

Comment: no....only TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined                 
 Component
D:/Reactprojects/birthday-remainder/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:322

Comment: Oops! thanx @Ramesh